# Why do people exit their spacecraft completely naked in this scene?

Tags: dont-look-up

After 22,740 years of deep sleep, the 2,000 people who left Earth before
the comet’s impact finally awaken on a lush alien planet. They step out
of their spacecraft, naked and in awe of the new habitable world before them.

Why do people exit their spacecraft completely naked in this scene?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

They evidently went into the cryopods naked and have emerged naked. The peons who were supposed to be taking care of these billionaires (dressing them, building them houses, etc) are all dead, having been killed several centuries earlier.

> **OLD BILLIONAIRE**: Where are the engineers and laborers? I want a house.
>
> **PETER ISHERWELL**: They were on pod 3. They’re all dead.
>
> <sub><sup>[Don't Look Up - Screenplay](https://assets.scriptslug.com/live/pdf/scripts/dont-look-up-2021.pdf)</sup></sub>

The punchline is that for all their (now worthless) money, they lack even the most basic skills, clothing themselves and finding shelter.

> **OLD BILLIONAIRE:** *I’ll give anyone who builds me a house ten million dollars.*
>
> **CONGRESSMAN TENANT:** *Hell I’ll give 20 million.*
>
> **PETER ISHERWELL:** *I’m offering a billion.*
>
> **OLD BILLIONAIRE** *5 billion.*
>
> **PETER ISHERWELL:** *20 billion.*
>
> They continue on with no takers as we pull out

Comment: You would think rhat if they could build a Ship that could last that long, they would have some kind of fabric that would allow them to have racks of clothes waiting.

Comment: Sounds like a variation of the Golgafrincham Ark Fleet Ship B, and "_Since we decided a few weeks ago to adopt the leaf as legal tender, we have, of course, all become immensely rich_".

Comment: Whoever put all of the workers in one pod and all of the bosses in another didn't think things through.

Comment: @EvilSnack - Overall the entire plan seems ill-thought-out.

Comment: I think this was the ending they were going to use but ultimately didn't. I remember an interview to this effect, and when I saw the movie they were attacked by creatures.

Comment: @EvilSnack whoever put *old people* on the ship didn't think things through.  Or maybe they watched Dr. Strangelove one to many times...

Comment: Obviously, @EvilSnack, the wealthy people paid for 1st class accommodations, while all the peons required to make society work could only afford stowage. May not have gone to plan... Kinda like how we determined a couple of years ago just what an "essential" employee actually is.

Comment: @MarkFoskey I can confirm. None of this dialogue is in the movie.